# Spotify API: How to get access token for only myself

Tags: spotify

I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/build-your-own-playlist-generator-with-spotifys-api-in-python-ceb883938ce4) to get the track list from my Discover Weekly playlist. The tutorial mentions that I need to get an OAuth token for my own account before requesting the playlist info. This is done by going to a random Console page and click on 'Get token' at the end of the page (which requires me to log into my Spotify account and approves the Console to access my account data).

[image: Get OAuth token]

However, I want to acquire this token programmatically, instead of manually clicking on 'Get token' and logging into my account every time I need this token. What I have is:

- My Spotify user ID (from my Account page)
- The Spotify client ID for an application I just created under Spotify for Developers
- The client secret for this application
- Basic knowledge of how to send GET and POST requests (using Python's `requests` library)

How can I get an OAuth token, or at least generate a new token each time, using some of these above 
information?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you're trying to do. If all you want is a token to query the api to lookup songs/artists/etc., then you can use the [Client Credentials](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) auth flow that doesn't require any user input. All you need to do here is exchange your client ID and secret for an `access_token` that you'll use in subsequent requests.

If you want access or change certain user information, you'll have to use one of the two other flows on the [same spotify authorization page](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/). You'll need to pass a list of scopes with this request, directing the user to a spotify-url-based authorization page, and be able to give it a redirect url that will handle the receiving of the `access_token` object once the user logs in to the spotify page.

<s>I don't think there's a way to implement one of these flows where you need to request user scopes without having some sort of web server running to accept the redirect passed into the spotify auth url and then save the given token.</s>
After looking at the link you posted for spotify's console pages, it looks like you can use any of those API requests to generate a token including the scopes you want. All it's doing is performing the normal authorization flow in the background, skipping the step where it returns a secret to you that your server that you can then exchange for an `access_token` and `refresh_token`. Using the spotify console pages seems like an easy quick way to get scripts or prototypes running without having to deal with setting up your own webserver.